# Deploying Rails React application on Heroku without webpack dev server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku, deployment, react-rails

I precompiled assets in production mode and deployed to heroku, but css and js doesn't seem to work. 
But when i configure a webpack dev server in heroku everything seems to work.
Do we need an additional server for react to work, or just precompiling the assets is enough.

I have added react via webpacker gem.

Comment: Are you using one of react-rails or react_on_rails? If yes please specify which one.

Comment: I have added react via webpacker gem, added to the question.